# Question on efficiency how maps are getting populated

Tags: apex, map, before-trigger

In the below code, is there a more efficient way create the maps that check for email and phone comparisons? I am looping twice over the same collection of records. please note, this trigger handler class is running in the before insert and before update context. In my test class I bulk tested with 200 records and the the most CPU time used in any of the test methods was 187ms and the largest heap size of the test methods executing was 27923. Is it possible to eliminate that second loop of the same collection of records and/or a more elegant way of handling populating those maps?

```
My_SObject__c[] newCollection = trigger.new;

global void handle() {     
    checkDuplicateRecords(getExistingSObjectRecords(buildQuery()));
}

private string buildQuery() {
    String retval = '';
    Set<String> filters = new Set<String>();
    for(My_SObject__c u : newCollection) {
        filters.add(String.format('(Email__c = \'\'{0}\'\' OR Phone__c = \'\'{1}\'\')',new String[]{u.Email__c,u.Phone__c}));         
    }
    retval = string.format('select Id, Email__c, Phone__c from My_SObject__c where {0}',new String[]{string.join(new List<String>(filters),' OR ')});
    return retval;
}

private List<My_SObject__c> getExistingSObjectRecords(string query) {
    List<My_SObject__c> retval = Database.query(query);
    return retval;
}

private void checkDuplicateRecords(List<My_SObject__c> existingSObjectRecords) {
    Map<String, My_SObject__c> emailToUserMap = new Map<String, My_SObject__c>();
    Map<String, My_SObject__c> phoneToUserMap = new Map<String, My_SObject__c>();
    for(My_SObject__c u : existingSObjectRecords) {
        emailToUserMap.put(u.Email__c, u);
        phoneToUserMap.put(u.Phone__c, u);
    }
    for(My_SObject__c u : newCollection) {
        if(emailToUserMap.containsKey(u.Email__c)) {
            u.Email__c.addError('There is already an record with this email address);
        }
        else if(phoneToUserMap.containsKey(u.Phone__c)) {
            u.Email__c.addError('There is already a record with this phone number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you could avoid populating maps/checking maps when email or phone is null if that is common but I'm not sure why 187 ms and 27K of heap is an issue; You could also use SFDC DuplicateRules perhaps and avoid apex altogether

Comment: This is what I would call an attempt at "micro-optimization". Sure, I imagine there is a way to avoid an explicit second loop over `newCollection`, but have you tried to measure how much time an additional loop over a small (i.e. < 100k) collection takes? Measuring should always be the first step in optimization. Put frankly, I think trying to avoid a second loop here is a waste of time that would save you _at most_ a few units of CPU time.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this code, but it's not the maps. I'll elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems, so let's go through this.

```
global void handle() {
```

Best Practice is to not use global if not necessary. And it's not necessary here.

```
private string buildQuery() {
```

Methods are, by default, private, you don't need to specify this. Further, there is no need to build this query dynamically. You think you're being optimal (?), but really, it's much faster to just write:

```
[SELECT Email__c, Phone__c FROM MySObject__c WHERE Email__c = :emails OR Phone__c = :phones]
```

This inline query does the same as building your query from scratch and does so much more efficiently.

Also, you have two logic bugs, in the same section.

```
if(emailToUserMap.containsKey(u.Email__c)) {
  u.Email__c.addError('There is already an record with this email address);
} else if(phoneToUserMap.containsKey(u.Phone__c)) {
  u.Email__c.addError('There is already a record with this phone number);
}
```

Should be:

```
if(emailToUserMap.containsKey(u.Email__c)) {
  u.Email__c.addError('There is already an record with this email address');
} 
if(phoneToUserMap.containsKey(u.Phone__c)) {
  u.Phone__c.addError('There is already a record with this phone number');
}
```

You want to check if both conditions so that the user can be informed of all errors at once.

Further, you're not actually using the Maps as maps, so just make them Sets.

In addition, your logic is incorrect; you forgot to check for existing records already in the collection. Use `after insert` and `after update` so you can exclude the records currently in the trigger context (or they'll block themselves).

There's nothing wrong with the pattern in general; I call this the [Aggregate-Query-Update](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) pattern, and almost every bulkified code will use this pattern or a variant.

You asked about heap usage: your algorithm is storing data it doesn't need to longer than it doesn't need to. You can simply use an inline query (as stated above).

You can also, if you were really stressed for heap, decide to discard data when you're done with it.

Here's an extreme example of minimal heap, minimal CPU time that corrects your logic bugs as well (mostly, anyways).

```
My_SObject__c[] newCollection = trigger.new;
```

...

```
public void handle() {     
    checkDuplicateRecords();
}

void checkDuplicateRecords() {
    Set<String> emails = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> phones = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> dupEmails = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> dupPhones = new Set<String>();
    // Aggregate - Gather the data we want to query
    for(My_SObject__c record: newCollection) {
        emails.add(record.Email__c);
        phones.add(record.Phone__c);
    }
    // Ignore nulls
    emails.remove(null);
    phones.remove(null);
    // Query - for the data we're interested in finding
    for(My_SObject__c record: [
        SELECT Email__c, Phone__c 
        FROM My_SObject__c 
        WHERE Email__c = :emails AND 
            Phone__c = :phones AND 
            Id NOT IN :newCollection]) {
        dupEmails.add(record.Email__c);
        dupPhones.add(record.Phone__c);
    }
    // Discard nulls, they can't be duplicates
    dupEmails.remove(null);
    dupPhones.remove(null);
    // Discard the filter criteria, optional
    emails = phones = null;
    // Update - the records based on the data we found from the query
    for(My_SObject__c u : newCollection) {
        if(dupEmails.contains(u.Email__c)) {
            u.Email__c.addError('There is already an record with this email address');
        }
        if(dupPhones.contains(u.Phone__c)) {
            u.Phone__c.addError('There is already a record with this phone number');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! @sfdcfox I appreciate the detail on your response. The reason I am using 'global` on the handle method is because I'm using a trigger framework with an interface, which specifies global as the assessor. Point taken on private methods and excellent check on the logic bugs. I didn't see those. I actually saw an old post with the dynamic query using the filter criteria that you replied to with that example. I thought it was really an elegant! I actually initially used sets. Why should this be in after context? Wouldn't the new record already be inserted?

Comment: @Dman100 (a) interface methods may be implemented as public/global regardless of the interface's access level. (b) I remember dynamic query, but that was to find combinations of AND filters (c) the after insert/update phase is a "temporary save". This assures you that your validations won't be violated because of Before Save flows or other triggers. Also, your logic had a bug where all updates would fail, because the records queried themselves... there's still a bulk unique issue in the first loop you could address if that's a concern.

Comment: Thank you @sfdxfox I refactored based on your input and using the sets was an improvement. Thanks for the pointer on being able to use a public assessor on the handle method even though the interface implementation is global. I'm still a little fuzzy on the using the after context with the trigger validation but I'm working thru that one.Thanks again sir! Always great input from you and it is appreciated!